# Ordered Conditional Type Safety in Arrays?

Tags: swift, struct, type-safety, generic-constraints

Is there a way to achieve ordered conditional type safety in Arrays?

For example if I want a DSL like way to create a burger I might want to say something like:

```swift
let burgerComponents = .burger(
    .buns(2),
    .beefPatty(1),
    .lettuce(),
    .mustard(),
    .mushrooms()
)
```

Where if you add the bun type you cannot add it again to that array. If you add the beefPatty you cannot add it again and so on.

A naive approach would be to create a `Struct`:

```swift
struct Burger {

    let buns: Int
    let patties: Int
    let lettuce: Bool
    let mustard: Bool
    let mushrooms: Bool

    init(
        buns: Int = 2,
        patties: Int = 1,
        lettuce: Bool = false,
        mustard: Bool = false,
        mushrooms: Bool = false) {
        self.buns = buns
        self.patties = patties
        self.lettuce = lettuce
        self.mustard = mustard
        self.mushrooms = mushrooms
    }
}

extension Burger {
     static func burger(
        buns: Int = 2,
        patties: Int = 1,
        lettuce: Bool = false,
        mustard: Bool = false,
        mushrooms: Bool = false) -> Burger {
        return Burger(buns: buns,
            patties: patties,
            lettuce: lettuce,
            mustard: mustard,
            mushrooms: mushrooms
        )
    }
}

let burger: Burger = .burger(buns: 2,
                             mushrooms: true)
```

However you cannot extend and add extra properties to the Burger struct (mayonaise, spicy mustard, etc.). The Typed Tagless solution solves that, however unfortunately not giving ordered conformance.

The `Struct` solution works if you need a non extensible solution, however since I'm creating an extensible API that other contributors would be able to add additional functionality to, the struct solution unfortunately does not solve those requirements!

Avenues I've explored are Phantom Types and Typed Tagless solutions.

#### Typed Tagless

```swift
struct Burger {
   let buns: Int 
   let beefPatty: Int 
   let lettuce: Bool 
   let mustard: Bool 
   let mushrooms: Bool 
}

enum BurgerAttributes {
    case buns(Int)
    case beefPatty(Int) 
    case lettuce
    case mustard
    case mushrooms
}

protocol BurgerComponents {
    static func buns(_ numberOfBuns: Int) -> Self 
    static func beefPatty(_ numberOfPatties: Int) -> Self 
    static func lettuce() -> Self 
    static func mustard() -> Self 
    static func mushrooms() -> Self 
}

struct BurgerProcess {
    let attributes: BurgerAttributes
    init(_ attributes: BurgerAttributes) {
        self.attributes = attributes
    }
}

extension BurgerProcess: BurgerComponents {

    static func buns(_ numberOfBuns: Int) -> BurgerProcess {
        return BurgerProcess(.buns(numberOfBuns))
    }

    static func beefPatty(_ numberOfPatties: Int) -> BurgerProcess {
        return BurgerProcess(.beefPatty(numberOfPatties))
    }

    static func lettuce() -> BurgerProcess {
        return BurgerProcess(.lettuce)
    }

    static func mustard() -> BurgerProcess {
        return BurgerProcess(.mustard)
    }

    static func mushrooms() -> BurgerProcess {
        return BurgerProcess(.mushrooms)
    }
}

protocol BurgerComposer {
    static func burger(_ processes: BurgerProcess...) -> Self 
}

struct BurgerBuilder {
    typealias BurgerCompose = () -> Burger 
    let compose: BurgerCompose 
    init(compose: @escaping BurgerCompose) {
        self.compose = compose
    }
}

extension BurgerBuilder: BurgerComposer {

    static func burger(_ processes: BurgerProcess...) -> BurgerBuilder {
        return BurgerBuilder { 

            var _buns: Int = 0
            var _patties: Int = 0
            var _lettuce: Int = 0
            var _mustard: Int = 0
            var _mushrooms: Int = 0

            for process in processes {
                switch process.attributes {
                case .buns(let buns):
                    _buns = buns
                case .beefPatty(let patties):
                    _patties = patties
                case .lettuce:
                    _lettuce = lettuce
                case .mustard:
                    _mustard = true
                case .mushrooms:
                    _mushrooms = true
                }
            }

            return Burger(
                buns: _buns,
                beefPatty: _patties,
                lettuce: _lettuce,
                mustard: _mustard,
                mushrooms: _mushrooms
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Now you should be able to create a Burger in a DSL like fashion:

```swift
let builder: BurgerBuilder = .burger(   
    .buns(2),
    .beefPatty(1),
    .lettuce(),
    .mustard(),
    .mushrooms()
)

let burger: Burger = builder.compose()
// Output: Burger(buns: 2, beefPatty: 1, lettuce: true, mustard: true, mushrooms: true)
```

So the Typed Tagless solution satisfies some requirements however if you would like to have conditional ordering it is not possible with the Typed Tagless solution.

With Typed Tagless you can define an unlimited number of attributes:

```swift
let builder = BurgerBuilder = .burger(
    .buns(2),
    .buns(0),
    .buns(10),
    .mustard()
)
```

There is no safety there for an external API user.

Is there a way to achieve ordered type conformance in the following format?

```swift
let burgerComponents = .burger(
    .buns(2),
    .beefPatty(1),
    .lettuce(),
    .mustard(),
    .mushrooms()
)
```

Comment: Why is the "ordered" requirement? Must `buns` come before `beefPatty`?

Comment: This is just a trivial example, but the point is to be able to "configure" an object where you cannot reuse previously used components. For example it doesn't make sense to initialize a view with multiple `.style()` components, no?